# how to pass parameters to stored procedure in mvc 3 using EF?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have mvc 3 application in which in session object i'm taking all values that is needed
to me as parameter to execute stored procedure.

If the userAction is update then execute stored procedure.

```
  public ActionResult Index(string userAction)
    {
       if(Session["Mappings"] != null)           
            ViewData["Message"] = "Mapping web grid";

        if (Session["PricingSecurities"] == null)
            Session["PricingSecurities"] = objRepository.GetPricingSecurityID();
        if (Session["Cusips"] == null)
            Session["Cusips"] = objRepository.GetCUSIP();

        SecurityMappingModel objModel = null;
        mappings = (List<SecurityMappingModel>)Session["Mappings"];

        objModel = new SecurityMappingModel();


        if (userAction == "Update" )
        {
            //please tell me how can i take values from Session[Mappings] and pass it to stored procedure?

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        objModel.PricingSecirities = (List<SelectListItem>)Session["PricingSecurities"];
        objModel.Cusips = (List<SelectListItem>)Session["Cusips"];
        ViewBag.Mappings = mappings;
        return View(objModel);
    }
```

How can i take values from Session[Mappings] and pass it to stored procedure?

Comment: are you using entity framework?

Comment: why no one dont know how to execute sp in mvc ;(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219643/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-mvc-by-ef

Comment: yes i have gone trough ... thanks but i want to know that in my case how can i do this as in `Session["Mappings"]` all my 3 parameters how can i get those values and pass it to stored procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to do something like this:

```
    using (MyEntitiesDataModel context = new MyEntitiesDataModel())
    {
        context.ExecuteStoreCommand(
            "exec MyStoredProc @param1={0}, @param2={1}",
            Session["foo"], Session["bar"]);
    }
```

...where **MyEntitiesDataModel** is your EF data model and **MyStoredProc** is the name of your stored proc.